# System.Data.SQLite not found on non-development PC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sqlite

I created a C# Project in Visual Studio and used an assembly on the SQLite 4.0 ADO Library from http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/.

The program runs fine on the development machine, but when I try to run it on another system, there always occurs an error, stating that System.Data.SQLite.dll cannot be found. I placed the file into the program directory. I also tried to put it into a directory that is listed under PATH. Any suggestions?

I'm using an openFileDialog to open the database. Here's the according code:

```
con = new SQLiteConnection();


                OpenFileDialog ofd1 = new OpenFileDialog();

                ofd1.Filter = "db Datei (*.db)|*.db|Alle Dateien (*.*)|*.*";

                if (ofd1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    filepath = ofd1.FileName;
                filepath.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
                con.ConnectionString = "Data Source= \"" + filepath + "\"";
    [...]
```

As already mentioned, this works on the development machine (Windows 7, 64bit).
The test machine runs in a virtualbox (Windows 7, 32bit).
The following exception occurs:

```
    System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Die Datei oder Assembly "System.Data.SQLite.dll" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
    Dateiname: "System.Data.SQLite.dll"
       bei WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       bei System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       bei System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       bei System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       bei System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

************** Geladene Assemblys **************
mscorlib
    Assembly-Version: 4.0.0.0.
    Win32-Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100).
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll.
----------------------------------------
WindowsFormsApplication1
    Assembly-Version: 1.0.0.0.
    Win32-Version: 1.0.0.0.
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/andi/Documents/My%20Dropbox/Own%20Public%20Folders/Public%20(Andy%20Malessa)/juralookup(Wir%20brauchen%20dringend%20nen%20Namen)/DataManagementTool/WindowsFormsApplication1.exe.
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly-Version: 4.0.0.0.
    Win32-Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel.
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll.
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly-Version: 4.0.0.0.
    Win32-Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel.
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll.
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly-Version: 4.0.0.0.
    Win32-Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel.
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll.
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms.resources
    Assembly-Version: 4.0.0.0.
    Win32-Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel.
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_de_b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.resources.dll.
----------------------------------------
mscorlib.resources
    Assembly-Version: 4.0.0.0.
    Win32-Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100).
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/mscorlib.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_de_b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.resources.dll.
----------------------------------------
```

So basically it says: "System.Data.SQLite.dll" or a dependency was not found.

The file is present in the application directory. Here's a file listing:
[image: File Listing]

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?  That might help us out.

Comment: I'll do tonight, after my work day. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Just updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are referencing the DLL stored in System.Data.SQLite.dll stored in the GAC on your development machine from your C# project and that DLL does not exist on the test client you would get that message. In that case you either need to install SQLlite on the test machine (thereby placing the DLL in the GAC), or change the reference in your project to point at the local DLL instaid.

Comment: I solved the problem by installing the SQLite ADO.NET 4.0 Provider in the test machine. Now I get another exception. But that's just an index out of bound. I know how to take care of that ;)
Just curious: How do I change the reference in a program to point to a local DLL?

Comment: Follow the steps in this link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to remove the reference stored in the GAC, copy the DLL to a new lib directory in your project, then add a reference to it.

Answer (score 2):

1. try referencing a version outside the gac
2. did you provide the right version (ie. 32 vs 64 bit)?

I had this problem as well and I think the first point fixed it. The machine you deploy it on doesn't have it in the gac obviously, and if you reference that version, it won't be found in the other places. At least that's the experience I had.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give us more details about the exception. In the mean time, try adding the following to your app.config:

```
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
<remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/>
<add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite"/>
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Comment: This will be necessary as well after he fixed the problem of not finding the assembly at all - your problem will fix not finding the provider which will happen after he found the assembly.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. Here is what I did and found:
I hooked into the AppDomain's AssemblyLoad event and traced all the assemblies that got loaded. I had added a reference to a class in System.Data.SQLite.dll to force loading before it was used by Fluent NHibernate. Lo and behold, SQLite was loaded from the GAC. No idea how it got there because I just downloaded the ZIP file of the .Net provider.

This is the reason why System.Data.SQLite.dll is copied local in the project (Project A) that directly references it, but not in projects that reference project A. For them, copying is not necessary because the file resides in the GAC. In my specific case, the NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver would attempt to load the System.Data.SQLite assembly but for whatever reasons it failed to do so. Maybe it truly expects the assembly to be placed in the output folder, but then again I see AssemblyResolve attempts for that DLL, which should mean that it uses standard .Net methods to load the assembly.

In any case, the solution was to include and hook this AssemblyResolve handler in my data access DLL:

```
Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Name == "System.Data.SQLite")
        return typeof (CollationSequence).Assembly;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Hope this helps, Christoph

Comment: PS: I also tried to remove System.Data.SQLite from the GAC but it told me:
Unable to uninstall: assembly is required by one or more applications
Pending references:
SCHEME: <WINDOWS_INSTALLER>  ID: <MSI>  DESCRIPTION : <Windows Installer>

Answer (score 2):

For people that installing ADO.NET SQLite Provider on client machine is out of the option:
Please download the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555) for 32bit and [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632) for 64bit windows and install them on client machines. That solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DEPENDS.EXE` to find `DLLs` which are heeded to your `System.Data.SQLite.dll` library.

In my case `System.Data.SQLite.dll` did not want to load without `msvcr100.dll` (C Runtime Library  for native code). Adding it to the application directory solved the problem.

Note: C Runtime Library is platform dependent!